# Ant's optional tasks are not available on CentOS

Tags: ant, centos, task, option-type

When I run ant on CentOS to build java project I receive an error:

```
Could not create task or type of type: replaceregexp
```

ant -diagnostics shows that optional tasks are not available. How I can install optional tasks for ant?

Ant is installed from CentOS package.

Comment: Put the optional tasks jar in the Ant install's `lib` dir.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Works for me:

```
yum install ant-nodeps
```

Comment: Don't you also have to install the missing regexp jar? "yum install ant-apache-regexp"??.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, doesn't look like it. Worked perfectly for me :) Thanks Junky! :D

Comment: Tested on Centos5. It may not work on later versions.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command, to download the jars associated with ANT's optional tasks:

```
ant -f $ANT_HOME/fetch.xml -Ddest=user -Dm2.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

For a full explanation,
see the [ANT Manual documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks).

Comment: There is no fetch.xml in the ANT_HOME directory.

Comment: Ant 1.7.0 started the outsourcing of optional tasks to Antlibs. This was also the version that introduced the "fetch.xml" script in ANT_HOME. (See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/tags/ANT_170/)

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install ant-apache-regexp
```

It will install the required optional task (jar).

```
yum search ant
```

One can do a quick search to get a list of other ant related packages.

Answer (score 1):

try 
**yum list 'ant*'** 
to see available ant packages.

In my case
**yum install ant-antlr.x86_64** worked.